# Objects are not affected by lights in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, light, import

I've imported obj file to blender and tried to add textures, but it failed with cycles.

In internal renderer everything seems ok, normal map works, specular map too. Diffuse has good visibility. But in cycles everything is very dark, normal map won't work along with specularity. And what is more - lights don't affect the object at all! Only world beckground affects the object.

With default cube everything is alright, so there is some problem in that object, but i don't know how to find it. I've already done converting tris to quads, removing doubles and clearing custom split normals, but it does not helped tho.

Here are screens of cycles and blender internal of the same object (there is no texture in cycles, to show that lights have no effect, while hemi is set to 100. with texture it would be boring almost black object). Notice normal map effect in internal render, while there is none in cycles, but nodes are set for it.

blend file: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/43121

[image]
[image]

Comment: is the hemi in an active (visible) layer ? On top of the screen shot : 0/0 lamps. So the hemi is on layer 2 or 10, maybe.

Comment: yeah. that is strange, because hemi is on 1st layer and enabled. i added blend file

Comment: to me, it works... just give the hemi more strength (note that hemi are like sun in in Blender2.77)

Comment: and what can you say about normal map? there is none applying in cycles, but works ok in BI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made it a little bit different then @lemon.

- Light changed to *Sun* > Emission 70.
- Normal connected to Glossy material.

[image: Shadow]

[image: Material]

[image]

Comment: yes, you are right

Comment: @CurlyBrace, LukeD answer is better. You should consider to validate his answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just few little things to change :

- The diff texture is nearly black (so that explain that few colors are visible)
- Your diff texture node was on 'non color data'
- I added the specular map
- Normal map is ok
- Lamp : strength keeped to 1 (was the diff texture problem)

[image]

[image]

Comment: wow! are you sure that you've only changed the diffuse texture? that's amazing! seems like i know nothing about cycles, lol.

Comment: but i can't understand how did you changed it? it seems to be still dark and i see no additional color manipulation nodes..

Comment: It came 'naturally'... Check if I have changed other things, but I don't think so... main thing : you have your rendering ok !

Comment: @curlybrace, what do you mean by " it seems to be still dark and i see no additional color manipulation nodes" ?

Comment: @curlybrace, all is due to the specular map. If not the model is black as the diff texture is.

Comment: now i've got the thing. specular map brought everything to live. thank you!